# Possible bug on Android Starter SDK initialization

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using the Starter SDK v3.13.2.8 to perform auto-suggest searches in an Android app. It works well on Android versions 9 and 4.2. But on Android 5.1.1 (API 22), the app crashes. Here's the stack trace:

```
11-01 16:24:09.022 341-430/com.example.myapp.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
    Process: com.example.myapp.debug, PID: 341
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getActiveNetwork()Landroid/net/Network; in class Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.net.ConnectivityManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
        at a.a.a.a.a.v0.a(MapsUtils.java:23)
        at a.a.a.a.a.v0.a(MapsUtils.java:20)
        at a.a.a.a.a.h.e(AnalyticsTrackerExternal.java:6)
        at a.a.a.a.a.h.d(AnalyticsTrackerExternal.java:1)
        at a.a.a.a.a.h$c.run(AnalyticsTrackerExternal.java:50)
        at a.a.a.a.a.h$i.run(AnalyticsTrackerExternal.java:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

In order for this exception to be thrown, I don't even need to dispatch the request. All I need to do is to initialize the map engine:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        MapEngine.getInstance().init(ApplicationContext(this)) {
            Log.d("HereInit", "$it")
        }
    }
}
```

Before the app crashes, though, it's possible to see the log output from the `MapEngine.init` callback:

```
11-01 16:24:10.079 341-341/com.example.myapp.debug D/HereInit: NONE
```

Comment: Thank you for reporting this. Our engineering team is looking into this and will get back to you soon.

Comment: Thank you for reporting. Fix will be included in SDK 3.14 release.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any expected date for this new release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix will be included in SDK 3.14 release. From all projects tab inside the portal, the new version which is 4.1 can be downloaded.